# Error when connect mongodb using promise module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-modules

I'm new to `nodejs`. I'm using `promise` module in which connect
`mongodb`. But I'm facing the following error.

```
(node:6827) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
    at /home/luan1412167/Desktop/nodejs_tutorial/mongodb/promise.js:11:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:6827) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(function(err, client){
    // if (err) throw err;
    if (err) {
        console.error('An error occurred connecting to MongoDB: ', err);
    }
    var db = client.db('Employee');
    // db.collection('Employee').updateOne(
    //     {
    //         'EmployeeName' : 'LuanDao'
    //     },
    //     {
    //         $set : {'EmployeeName' : 'AAA'}
    //     }
    // );
    client.close();
});
```

I tried hard to fix it. But I can't fix yet.
Any suggest is appreciate. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I think that I used it as an instance in the code above. My error is at connect function. Anw, Maybe I don't understand your thought. So you can talk to me in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used promises, code needs to be modified with catch statement. Modify your code as below:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then((db) => {
    var db = client.db('Employee');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error('An error occurred connecting to MongoDB: ', err);
  });
```